# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: lista

Estou recebendo um código de erro como se o parâmetro da minha função fosse um INTEIRO, mas é uma LISTA. O erro diz que não posso usar len(lista) porque entende que lista é um INTEIRO.

[image: Erro na função len]

Comment: Mas o parâmetro é um inteiro. Para enviar uma sub-list para a função `soma_lista`, você deveria utilizar `lista[i+1:]`, com esses dois pontos no final, indicando que a sub-lista deve ser gerada a partir da posição `i+1`, até o final.

Answer (score -1):

O seu erro é simples mas eu entendi a sua confusão.
`lista` é uma Lista.
Mas `len(lista)` é um inteiro.
O código de erro não diz que `lista` é um inteiro. Ele diz que `last` o é.

A sua Lista tem 6 itens.
Quando vc faz `last = len(lista)` vc está dizendo que last é igual ao resultado do length menos 1.  Nesse caso, o resultado é 5.

É isso mesmo que vc quer? Ou vc queria retirar um item da lista?

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).